# Calling a class via a proxy class returns same object

Tags: oop, python-2.7, magic-methods

Why calling a class via proxy class returns same object ?

EDIT:
  I call two different attributes, but how the id is still same for two different objects ?

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
      print "In Init"
      self.a = 40

   def __getattr__(self, attr):
      if attr in ["b", "c"]:
        return 42

       raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" % (self.__class__, attr))

 class Proxy(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, type=None, *args, **kwargs):
       return A()

 class C(object):
    tran = Proxy()

 class D(C):
    def sample(self):
       x = id(self.tran)
       y = id(self.tran)
       print x == y

  d = D()
  d.sample()
```

Whenever tran is accessed it returns the same object and how the ids for x and y are same ?

Comment: When I run this code, I get "In Init" printed twice, then "False". Is that different than what you're seeing? It may be that you're getting confusing results due to saving only the `id` of the value you get from `self.tran`, which may be reused after the `A` object is created and then destroyed (since there are no references kept to it). Try `x=self.tran; y=self.tran; print id(x)==id(y)` which should always be print `False`.

Comment: I see always a True, when I run this code.

Comment: Well, now you're comparing the ids of two integers. Small `int`s are cached, so `id(42)` will always equal `id(42)` even if you get one or both of them from other sources (like `6*7`). The original version of the question was actually more interesting!

Comment: Ah yes, the original was actually I am trying to understand that how Proxy which I expected will return different id returned same id for `self.tran`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue you're having is becuase you're only saving the `id` of the objects you're getting. In CPython, the `id` is the memory address of the object. If the object has no references left (as is the case here after the `id` call ends), it will be deallocated and its memory address may be reused by a different object.

Try keeping a reference to the actual object returned, and calling `id` on it later. This will make sure your two objects are alive at the same time, which will mean they'll have different `id`s:

```
def sample(self):
    x = self.tran # don't call id yet!
    y = self.tran # we need to keep references to these objects
    print id(x) == id(y) # This will print False. You could also test "x is y".
```